# Estimators for Uniform distribution (MLE) on interval $[a, 2a]$

Tags: uniform-distribution, estimation, maximum-likelihood

We assume that $X \sim \text{Unif}\,(a, 2a)$ on $[a;2a]$ where $a>0$ and $\{ x_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ are i.i.d realizations from this distribution.

How can I prove that the estimator $\hat{a} = \text{min}(x_i)$ is well-defined? Meaning that for all $i$, $$\hat{a} \leq x_i \leq 2\hat{a}$$ holds?

Can it be also proved that the estimator $\hat{a} = \frac{\text{max}(x_i)}{2}$ is also well-defined such that: $$\hat{a} \leq x_i \leq 2\hat{a}$$ holds as well for all $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assume that $\hat a = \min \{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$. Since $a \leq \hat a \leq x_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$, it follows that $2a \leq 2 \hat a$, and since $x_i \leq 2a$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$, we see that $\hat a \leq x_i \leq 2\hat a$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$.

Your second part about $\max$ makes no sense. How could every $x_i$ be at least as big as the maximum? I think what you are reaching for is $\hat a / 2 \leq x_i \leq \hat a$, assuming that $\hat a = \max \{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$.

In the future I suggest using different notation for $\min$ and $\max$.

If you are trying to find the MLE, check out question 3 on page 4 here: [STAT 135 Solutions to Homework 4](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjioujvyevrAhVLnp4KHXizAiYQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbcourses.berkeley.edu%2Ffiles%2F55481701%2Fdownload%3Fdownload_frd%3D1&usg=AOvVaw1sPQfxTPz5ckIO3U12rT5E).

Comment: Thanks for this reply. This makes sense. And I made a typo on the second part, but I think I figured it out as well.
The correction being: $\hat{a} = \frac{\text{max}(x_i)}{2}$

Comment: What notation for min and max do you suggest? Do you mean including the variable to minimize over? Like $min_i$?

Comment: You can just use $\min$ and $\max$, or $m$ and $M$, or whatever is easy to write and keep clear in your mind. The hat notation is usually reserved for your estimator. In other words, the MLE for $a$ that you calculate (again, see the link) would be written $\hat a$.

Comment: Ah, I think I get your point. I was trying to make the point that the estimator $\hat{a}$ equals the minimum of the sample realizations. I'll try to make it clear next on! Thanks a bunch

Comment: Notice in the link that the estimator is not actually the minimum. It's half the maximum. In the link the equation for the MLE is $\hat{\theta} = \max / 2$, so you can see how confusing it would be if you used $\hat{\theta}$ for the estimator and the maximum.

Comment: This clears it up! Thank